# нужно последовательно ввести список целых чисел: a=[int(input(i) for i in range(n))]

Tags: python-3.x

```
n=int(input())
a=[int(input(i) for i in range(n))]
```

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'generator'

Comment: Чтоб было понятно за что минусы и голоса за закрытие: за то, что не читал текст ошибки, за то что не скопировал его сюда, за тупое "не работает".

Comment: Спасибо, учту на будущее.

Comment: Подскажите, внесенные мной изменения оставили вопрос недопустимым? Я просто не пойму, почему. Мне реально помогли ответы, другим, полагаю, тоже. Уже боюсь задавать следующий вопрос.

Comment: Не оставили, но вопрос был закрыт ещё до внесения поправок.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скобку не в том месте поставили

```
a=[int(input(i)) for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [input("Введите {}: ".format(i)) for i in range(5)]
Введите 0: 0
Введите 1: 1
Введите 2: 2
Введите 3: 3
Введите 4: 4

print(a)
```

['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

Comment: Подскажите, а что за функционал .format(i) и в каком разделе можно ознакомиться с подробностями?

Comment: @samsusam https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html

Answer (score 1):

***Код:***

```
n = int(input())

a = [int(input(f'{i+1}: ')) for i in range(n)]
print(a)
```

*stdout:*

```html
3
1: 2
2: 2
3: 8
[2, 2, 8]
```